# Symfony 2: Doctrine Cache Namespace

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, namespaces

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: xcache
            namespace: %foobar%
```

hi, i want set the doctrine cache namespace via parameter like %foobar%. the parameter %foobar% will set via compilerPass

```
class FoobarCompiler implements CompilerPassInterface {
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->setParameter('foobar', uniqid());
    }
}
```

and this compilerPass ist register in a bundle class via:

```
public function build(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $container->addCompilerPass(new \FQNS\Compiler\FoobarCompiler());
}
```

but i get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>    You have requested a non-existent parameter "foobar".

any idea how can i set the doctrine cache namespace via this parameter "foobar" ?

greez & thx,
  sky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is this snippet:

```
class FoobarExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface {

    ...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->setParameter('foobar', uniqid());
    }
}
```

it is importand to add the "PrependExtensionInterface" interface !

greez & thx,
  sky...